# Purpose of element.setAttribute()?

Tags: javascript

If there is an element like this:

```
var c = document.createElement('a');
```

Then one can add the attribute name simply by doing:

```
c.name = "a1";
```

What is the purpose of `setAttribute()` if one can just use the dot notation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An attribute is not the same thing as a property.

Attributes are usually created in your HTML, and will become an object member of `element.attributes`. Some will also set a corresponding property.

There are some attributes that update when you change the property, but others that do not. For example, the .value property will not change the attribute on input elements. Or custom properties do not become custom attributes.

Most of the time you probably want to set the property, but if you want to change the attribute, then in some cases you must use `setAttribute`

Comment: Is there some documentation somewhere I can read about the difference between attribute and properties?

Comment: I don't know right now. Mozilla network probably has some information.

Comment: It depends on the attribute. As my answer says, there are some attributes that will update when you change the property. But your somecustomattribute property does not become an attribute. Do this alert(sss.getAttribute("somecustomattribute")); and you will get null

Comment: Well that's a matter of retrieving the attribute. getAttribute() is rarely used if at ALL. Jquery returns the attribute of a dom correctly, and it does change when changing a property of a previously properly defined attribute. The thing though is that you can't define it by setting a property, but by doing so you CAN change its value (if it exists).

Comment: I should have given an exmaple with setAttribute. Like this sss.setAttribute("somecustomattribute",'aaaa'); alert(sss.somecustomattribute); The alert will be undefined.

Comment: Well, I don't know, may be the function is bugged / deprecated or by 'attribute' it means something else than we usually mean by.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant in my answer when I said that there's a difference between attributes and properties. Sometimes they are linked, and sometimes not. Usually with custom attributes like that one they're not linked. It is the standard attributes that automatically become a property, like "id" for example.

Comment: Well, my head is going to blow up.. It is still not clear how it operates though.

Comment: An attributes is part of HTML, like `<div theattr="the value">`. Because it has a custom attribute that is not standard, it only becomes an attribute, and not a property. So you can do `div.getAttribute("theattr")` but not `div.theattr`. If it was standard, like `"id="theID"`, then the browser makes sure it is available both ways.

Comment: Yep, I also figured my mistake with the above fiddle, it should be `alert(sss.getAttribute('somecustomattribute'));` which does work as expected, contrary to what I thought of it. Indeed so, properties with the name of our custom attribute don't exist as such, and aren't associated with it. But when I create attribute with Jquery.attr() - it does seem to link the properties with the respected attributes.

Comment: Anyway we agree on that we shouldn't refer to them as properties for the non standard attributes. Thanks for discussion :)

Answer (score 2):

I'd use `getAttribute/setAttribute` to make it clear that you're working with DOM elements. Minimizing ambiguity is a plus!

However, this is what [quirksmode.org](http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/w3c_core.html#attributes) has to say about atrributes:

> Attributes
>
> A bloody mess. Try influencing attributes in this order:
>
> 1. Try getting or setting a specific property, like x.id or y.onclick.
> 2. If there is no specific property, use getAttribute() or
>      setAttribute().
> 3. If even that doesn't work, try any other method or
>      property in the table below. Most have horrible browser
>      incompatibility patterns, though.
> 4. Avoid attributes[]. It's worse
>      than anything else.

Comment: well minimizing excess code is good too....It looks like it sais to start w/ the dot notation and from there try get/set if that does not work.

Answer (score 2):

Who says you can do either?

Well, okay you can. But seriously, "who says?", because it mostly comes down to that.

In the beginning, there was Netscape Navigator 2, the first web browser to support Javascript, and indeed being a few months prior to server-side use in Netscape Enterprise Server, the first anything to support Javascript (called "Livescript" in a beta version but quickly renamed "Javascript" because it was 1995 and putting the word "java" in anything was a sure-fire way to get about 20,000 column-inches out of tech journalists who spent the rest of their time wondering confused around coffee wholesalers wondering where the press releases and promotional schwag was).

The object model at the time was pretty small, to the point that you could learn it to the point where you could hold the entire model in your head in a couple of days. For most elements, you couldn't actually do very much with them. A lot of things were quite fiddly (where you can find the current value of a `<select id="selId" name="selName">` today with `document.getElementById('selId').value`  and a few other ways, then you would need `document.forms[0]["selName"].options[document.forms[0]["selName"].selectedIndex].value`.

Then IE3 came out with Javascript too, NN 3 upped the ante by letting you change an image's `src` attribute. The browser wars had begun in earnest. Many veterans are still haunted by the memories of what they did.

The really obvious way to make a browser's document model better, was to have more and more things reflected by properties - preferably writable rather than read-only. The next-best thing was to have a slightly simpler and easier to remember way of changing something than the other browser (then they might make more web pages that worked in the latest version of your browser and didn't in your rival's).

Through keeping up a rapid pace of development, it was clear that Netscape would develop a new middleware platform that would make the position of Microsoft and Apple irrelevant, while the jury was out on whether yahoo or alta-vista had the approach to search and/or directory that would dominate the web. (Don't make long-term predictions about technology).

During the general trend of make-script-able-to-do-everything-to-everything, a lot of properties got named after the corresponding attribute when there was one, which is after all a pretty sensible way.

This is a bit inconsistent though. For one thing, most properties that correspond to attributes map string values to string values in a straight-forward way. One or two do not, such as the `href` attribute on anchor elements which gives you a richer object with properties reflecting parts of the URI (mostly because it was available from the early days before make-script-able-to-do-everything-to-everything). Which is both useful (if you want to break the URI down) and a nuisance because there's no good way of telling which is which.

At the height of this, they had something called DHTML, and something called dHTML, which were two ways to do pretty much the same thing in completely incompatible ways.

There's also the fact that javascript is loose in letting you add a new property to anything, and HTML lets you add in new attributes (debatable, depending on how strictly you stay to which standard, but this was the browser wars and new proprietary attributes were seemingly added by one browser or another every 4 minutes). Knowing whether a property would have any real effect on any given browser was a nuisance.

Meanwhile, in a distant International Standards Consortium, something called XML was being developed. It let you add all sorts of elements with all sorts of attributes in all sorts of ways. Ways of dealing with this in script were also added.

We needed a way to more consistently change the attributes of elements than that currently existing, and since it was obvious that all future versions of HTML would be XML applications (Don't make long-term predictions about technology) it made sense for it to be at least relatively consistent between the two.

It was also dawning on everyone, that having a more popular browser than everyone else wasn't going to turn anyone into the next Bill Gates (not even the current Bill Gates) so the advantages of having greater support for standard approaches rather than greater flashy-stuff-the-other-guy-can't-do became more apparent.

The [W3C DOM](http://www.w3.org/DOM/DOMTR) became more and more finalised and more and more supported. It gave us a more consistent way of setting attributes. It was more verbose, but you could know consistently what it was going to do, and it was also more powerful in creating, copying, changing and deleting parts of a document.

But old sites had to be kept going if possible, along with the fact that it does remain a useful shorthand for a lot of attributes to just set the corresponding property, so people weren't going to stop using it. Still, the DOM approach is supported to some extent by all browsers, giving much more consistency between them.

And then half the developers started using JQuery anyway.

Comment: @ThomasEding ts;di (too short, didn't inform).

Answer (score 1):

This is to make some custom attribute:

while its all fine to make `el.name='aaa';`

if you make `el.customsttr='a'` it will not work.

-- (unless it has been already defined, as pointed out below)

http://jsfiddle.net/sXdHB/

Application:

For example you have an img, with attr 'src', then you might want to add a custom atribute 'big_src' and then read it through some script to display a bigger one;

Comment: ... I don't think true...I made up the attribute speed like this.... image_element.speed = 500;...for some animation w/ out using that method...I just tacked it on and it works fine.

Comment: If it's already defined you can use it like that of course. Good point, I'll update it make it more clrear :)

Comment: Hiro, you are wrong about one thing.... it WOULD NOT create a custom attribute inside a dom. You can inspect the element with dev tools and see it hasn't got the custom attr as a tag.

Comment: It would only set a variable to the element, but it would not create a tag to that element. See here: http://jsfiddle.net/sXdHB/2/ - only if you uncomment the creation string would it then set the value of the custom tag

Comment: I'm inspecting with Google chrome - right click -> inspect :) I'll make fiddle that will alert all the tag for you to believe :) just wait

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/sXdHB/3/ here it is, see that initially it returns undefined for our attribute if it hasn't been properly defined previously

Comment: Your example uses jquery .attr(), which doesn't always use getAttribute. The question is asking about getAttribute. http://jsfiddle.net/sXdHB/5/

Comment: You are wrong, user1600680 the question is about `setAttribute` not `getAttribute`.

Comment: Yes, the question is about setAttribute. My mistake. But the result is the same if you use setAttribute to set the value, then dot notation to get the value.

Comment: Well, you are right then. It seems properties are not necessarily related to the attributes.